# how to extract css rule with special color in files

Tags: css, regex

could every one help me in this case, i have arounds 20k line css from multiple file css,
i need export only one rule for common style :

the file css example :

```
  #course-main .lay-06 .content-01,
    #course-main .lay-06 .content-02,
    #course-main .lay-06 .content-03 {
        width: calc(100% - 10px) !important;
        height: calc(33% - 10px) !important;
        margin: 5px !important;
        flex-shrink: 0;
        flex-grow: 0;
    }

.view-slide {
    width: 14px;
    height: 14px;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 7px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 1px solid #colorPrimary;
}
```

and i want to export this to:

```
.view-slide {
    border: 1px solid #colorPrimary;
}
```

mean remove another rules except css have line with `#colorPrimary;`
could i achieve my goal with regex ?

Comment: Could you explain more what you mean by 'extract'. You seem to know what the rule is so I don't understand what you are trying to do I'm afraid.

Comment: what language are you using the regex?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
/([\w#\.\-]+)\s*{[^{]*?([^;{]*#colorPrimary)/gms
```

The first group has the CSS selector and the second has the propriety.

You can try it [here](https://regex101.com/r/WnSc8J/1)